# Apply .conf file to other .conf

Tags: config, configuration-files

I'm looking any official way for .conf file import inside another .conf file but it seems that there is none and each .conf parser uses the format they need.

I'm using Ubuntu and I wanted to use some .conf variables values as values of other .conf files variables. For instance, having a `global.conf` with:

```
GLOBAL_VAR=things
```

and a `specific.conf` with:

```
SPECIFIC_MODULE.component.element = $GLOBAL_VAR
```

This will be primarly used for server adresses/usernames and such to change on demand in several scripts used to initialize and configurate the all system. Unfortunately the `specific.conf` that I have are required by applications that I have to launch.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your tags, I'm assuming that you mean shell configuration files.  If that's the case, then all you need to do is use the "`source`" keyword or the "`.`" operator (both do the same thing) to include one file from inside the other.  For example, my `.profile` includes the following:

```
# Include the '.bashrc' file, if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
. "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
```

If instead you mean configuration files for some utility that have the .conf file extension, then you'll need to provide more details.  There is no standard configuration file format, and each program does it a little differently.

Comment: sorry, I added those tags by mistake, it is really just .conf files, I was just trying to avoid creating some .template files that will be used to generate those .conf files every time a configuration changes

Comment: I've seen a few utilities that have a way to do something like that, but most don't.  What I end up doing in cases like yours is having a directory with all of the .conf files in it, plus a script that does something like `cat global.conf specific.conf > /path/to/target.conf` for all of the files.  It's not pretty, but it lets you push out updates to the global config with one click.

Comment: that's what I was thinking about doing it. I've done it in the past and I think it's time to create a more friendly interface to deal with that, but the bottom process will be something like that preferentially with auto detection of config change